# How to fix TypeScript update from 3.5.2 to 3.6.2 on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm triying to update my Reactjs project from TypeScript 3.5.2 to 3.6.3 but it keep giving me an error:

```
Failed to compile.

[internal]
TypeScript error in [internal](undefined,undefined):
Debug Failure. Unexpected node.
Node Identifier was unexpected.  TSINTERNAL_ERROR
```

When execute `yarn start` i saw this:

```
=============

WARNING: You are currently running a version of TypeScript which is not officially supported by typescript-estree.

You may find that it works just fine, or you may not.

SUPPORTED TYPESCRIPT VERSIONS: >=3.2.1 <3.6.0

YOUR TYPESCRIPT VERSION: 3.6.3

Please only submit bug reports when using the officially supported version.

=============
```

Anyone else have this error? We update our backend project from 3.5.2 to 3.6.3 without problemas, but frontend keep giving this messages